# End Tag For "table" Which Is Not Finished

Tags: html

I have a validation error on one of my pages. I cannot get rid of it and if I try to add anymore tags multiple errors come up.

Here is the code:

```
<table><caption>Records for the month of <span id="MonthName">January</span></caption></table>
```

Again, putting in `<td>` and `<tr>` tags make an error called Document type does not allow `<tr>` here etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table must have at least one table row (`<tr>`) element (or an explicit `<tbody>` which contains one).

> Again, putting in `<td>` and `<tr>` tags make an error called Document type does not allow `<tr>` here etc.

Where is "here"? You should be placing them after the caption element.

Comment: I tried that but the document type does not allow it. Where would I put the <tr> tag?

Comment: Like this? <table><caption><tr><td>Records for the month of <span id="MonthName">January</span></td></tr></caption></table>

Comment: No. After the caption *element*, you've put it after the caption start tag (which is *inside* the element).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1">
  <caption>Monthly savings</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```